# Resizing a png image without losing tranparency

Tags: image, png, transparency

I am trying to save a png file in database using C#.

Bitmap thumbnail = new Bitmap(file.InputStream);
 thumbnail = ImageUtilities.ResizeImage(thumbnail, Convert.ToInt32(width),Convert.ToInt32(height)); ImageUtilities.SaveJpeg(path,thumbnail,Convert.ToInt32(Resources.AppConstants.ExtractThumbnailQuality);

The image gets saved in database, but with a black background around the image. In short, it loses its transparency.
If I skip the resizing of image, instead of black background, a white background appears around the image.

Can anyone suggest, how to preserve the tranparency of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving the resized image as JPEG. JPEG does not support transparency. Save it as PNG instead

Comment: Yes, You are right. I used  thumbnail.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png);